# Делаю парсер. Нужно сделать вывод строк в csv фаил, проблема в том что я не могу вывести их в одну строку. Как это сделать?

Tags: python, csv

```py
for i in soup.select(".products-of-the-day__item.product-of-the-day"): 
    title1 = i.select(".product-of-the-day__name")
    title2 = i.select(".product-of-the-day__price.price") 
    output_file.writelines(title1[0].text + title2[0].text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output_file.writelines(f'{title1[0].text.strip()}    {title2[0].text.strip()}\n')
```